# Dump and restore a postgres database using pg_dump and pg_restore

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to dump and restore a Postgres database, at once.It means that when I restore it, I have nothing to do but call pg_restore.
To dump I tryed the follow two instructions:

```
pg_dump -U postgres  -f noc_backup_2022_12_06.dump -Fc treebase
```

and with the option -C (include the create db instructions)

```
pg_dump -U postgres  -C -f backup_2022_12_06.dump -Fc treebase
```

Notice that the file name in the first is noc_backup... in the second is backup...
Now I try to restore:
If I call the follow instructions :

```
pg_restore  -U postgres -fnoc_backup_2022_12_06.dump
pg_restore  -U postgres -fbackup_2022_12_06.dump
pg_restore  -U postgres -C -fbackup_2022_12_06.dump
pg_restore  -U postgres -C -fnoc_backup_2022_12_06.dump
```

It get stuck, no request of password, no error message, nothing happen I have to CTRL+C to unlock the prompt.

```
pg_restore  -U postgres -C  -dtreebase backup_2022_12_06.dump
pg_restore  -U postgres -C  -dtreebase noc_backup_2022_12_06.dump
pg_restore  -U postgres -dtreebase noc_backup_2022_12_06.dump
pg_restore  -U postgres -dtreebase backup_2022_12_06.dump
```

Each of them raise an error that the database "treebase" doesn't exists.
To successfully restore a database I have to login with psql and `CREATE DATABASE`.
Then I launch:

```
pg_restore  -U postgres -dtreebase noc_backup_2022_12_06.dump
```

And it works. Since the backup should be executed from the final user, I would make it easiest as possible, two  instructions to copy-paste and stop.
The question is :
How do restore whole database only with pg_restore

Comment: Reading the docs [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) and [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) would be a good start.  1) You would find that if you do `-Fc` in `pg_dump` you don't need to include the `-C`, that can be done on the `pg_restore` end.  2) You would know that if you use `-C`  `-d` points at the initial db you connect to so it needs to exist. The recommended db to connect  to is `postgres`. 3) Also with `pg_restore` that `-f` points at a file that you want to restore a plain text version of the dump to.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61016424/

Comment: @ Adrian Klaver,  I didn't dream those instruction at nigth, I read them somewhere, I'm struggling with this problem several days. And I think that who wrotes these documentation it has not clear how pg_dump and pg_restore works. The -Fc command is presented as "Custom Format", after several attempts, I discovered that is the only format that pg_restore reads, otherwise it says to use psql.  
@a_horse_with_no_name as a user wrote, those instructions raise the error : error: one of -d/--dbname and -f/--file must be specified . It also doesn't solve the problem

Comment: 1)  `pg_restore` can either restore to a file using `-f` creating the equivalent of  `pg_dump -Fp` or  to a database using `-d`. You cannot use both options at the same time. 2) Where ever you read the instructions from was wrong, that is why I pointed you at the docs. 3) The docs in the *Notes* sections give you numerous examples to work from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved, the winning combination is:
dump the database with the following instruction, with -C option to include the create database instruction:

```
pg_dump -U postgres -C  -f backup_2022_12_06.dump -Fc treebase
```

then to restore access to database postgres, not treebase and include the -C command to create the database

```
pg_restore  -U postgres -C -dpostgres -Fc backup_2022_12_06.dump
```

Comment: Per the docs [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) *-C ... This option is ignored when emitting an archive (non-text) output file. For the archive formats, you can specify the option when you call pg_restore.*